# How to use connection pool to postgresql in spark

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I have a spark (1.2.1 v) job that inserts a content of an rdd to postgres using [postgresql.Driver for scala](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async):

```
rdd.foreachPartition(iter => {

        //connect to postgres database on the localhost
        val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        var connection:Connection = null
        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
        val statement = connection.createStatement()

        iter.foreach(row => {
            val mapRequest = Utils.getInsertMap(row)
            val query = Utils.getInsertRequest(squares_table, mapRequest)

            try { statement.execute(query) } 
            catch {
                case pe: PSQLException => println("exception caught: " + pe);
            }
        })
        connection.close()
})
```

In the above code I open new connection to postgres for each partition of the rdd and close it. I think that the right way to go would be to use connection pool to postgres that I can take connections from (as described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)), but its just pseudo-code:

```
rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
// ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
}
```

**What is the right way to connect to postgres with connection pool from spark?**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**This code will work for spark 2 or grater version and scala , First you have to add spark jdbc driver.**

If you are using Maven then you can work this way. add this setting to your pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

write this code to scala file

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object PostgresConnection {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark =
        SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("DataFrame-Basic")
        .master("local[4]")
        .getOrCreate()

   val prop = new java.util.Properties
   prop.setProperty("driver","org.postgresql.Driver")
   prop.setProperty("user", "username")
   prop.setProperty("password", "password")
  val url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/databaseName"
  val df = spark.read.jdbc(url, "table_name",prop)
  println(df.show(5))
 }
}
```

Comment: This creates a new connection for each partition of `df` and does not use a ConnectionPool consisting of jdbc connections.